# Force Ubuntu to identify LAMP php installation

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I have installed LAMP in my ubuntu environment (16.04) which has apache, php (7.0.9), mysql...

Although the php functionality is there, when i type 'php -v' in the terminal, i get the message

> The program 'php' can be found in the following packages 
>   * php7.0-cli  
>   * hhvm

which as i understand means that ubuntu does not recognise the php installation from LAMP .

---

Is there a way to tell ubuntu that there is a php installation in opt/lamp... in order to recognise it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message you see is triggered by a shell function called `command_not_found_handle` defined in your system wide bashrc (`/etc/bash.bashrc`). This function is called by the bash when you enter the name of a binary which is not found in the current PATH. On Ubuntu, this uses a tool called command-not-found to search your input against a package database and suggest a package that might contain the command you entered.

Depending on how you installed your LAMP stack - by using apt-get a lot or unblobbing a big tar file - there are two answers to your question.

In case you did apt-get all the stack applications you just did not install the php-cli package. In that case you can do `sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli` and you are fine.

In your question you mention `/opt/lamp` which suggests that you did the unblob-a-tar thing. This means that you should have a php cli binary somewhere in a `bin` directory under your `/opt/lamp`. What you can do is

1. Call it using an absolute path, i.e. `/opt/lamp/bin/php -v`: this is perfect if you call it only now and then
2. You can add a symlink into your bin folder, i.e `ln -s /opt/lamp/bin/php /usr/bin/php`: helpful if the LAMP version is the only version in your system and you use it regulary
3. Add the path of the bin folder to your PATH environment: you might use this if the LAMP is an integral part of your system

`bin/php` is just an example here - your actual binary might be in a different directory under a different name. Replace it with the correct path once you found it.

If you install a full binary package in `/opt` it might be a good idea to check if it and if so how it uses libraries that exist in your core system. You can do this by issuing `ldd /opt/lamp/bin/php` and check the paths of the libs that are printed. Sometimes you get into trouble when those binaries still use your system libs but expect different versions.

Comment: Thank you @FredFoo your answer solved it. Very good explanation!